# How to decrease flash capacity space

Tags: disk-space, sd-card, storage-spaces, compact-flash

I have one old recorder and this recorder can't support over than 1 gb cf (compact flash) card. Now I can't find cf 1gb on stores!

Can I decrease for example cf 8 gb to 1gb?

Thank's

Comment: Probably No. You could try to create a partition that's just 1 GB but it's likely that it's incompatible due to other things (electrical or protocol) as well.

Comment: This ^^^ The limitation is not the partition size but the standard itself that old readers do not support.